# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN when accessing local website

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, television

I'm building a webapp, which should be accessible in the local network via http://deviceName.local. Therefore at the moment I only use and http not the safer https protocoll.

When trying to find it via my windows computer, phone or raspberry pi everything works fine.

Unfortunately, when targeting this site via Chrome from a TV like Samsung Flip Pro or Iiyama I'm always getting **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**.
I didn't find any firewall related settings in the Android Developer settings.

Does anybody have a clue why this is happening and how I can overcome this error?

I hope this the right forum. Otherwise please move this thread to another topic.

Thanks for helping

Comment: `via deviceName.local. ` That is impossible. What do you mean,? Give exact url please.

Comment: I mean when trying to access it via http:/deviceName.local/80. Here deviceName is the name of the machine, where the server runs.

Comment: If you use Chrome on a TV then what does this have to do with Android? Or Android progamming?

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with the android firewall settings. But that’s why I‘m asking.